# Can I paraphrase 'It's of no value, either.' into 'It's valueless, either.'?

Tags: usage

But in ***It's valueless, either.***, there is no negative, so ***too*** should be used, right?

So, ***It's valueless, too.*** is the right usage, is it?

What I want to know is whether you sometimes use ***It's valueless, either.*** in informal English?

Answer (score 2):

The general rule is that *either* is used with negations, *too* with affirmative statements.

> I love ice cream too.

> I don’t like liver either.

“It is valueless” is affirmative, so yes, the right adverb is *too*.

It should be said, though, that this rule isn’t ironclad. (In language, what rule is?) Consider,

> It has no value either.

Though “It has” is affirmative, it’s still idiomatic to use *either* because of the *no*. An alternative sentence meaning the same thing,

> It doesn’t have [any] value either.”

does conform to the rule.

To answer your second question, no, “It’s *X* either” would not be said for any *X* that wasn’t of the form *X* = “not *Y*.”